# Running R Keras model with custom loss crash when run twice on different data sets

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function

I am trying to develop some specific type of neural net with a special type of loss function. The loss is somewhat strange but in my project in actually make sens.

Any how I am trying to first set up the architecture and then fit the model to different data set x_train and y_train and x_train2 and y_train2.

I really don t get why it crashes when fitted to the x_train2 and y_train2.

Here is the error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) : 
  RuntimeError: in user code:

    File  ...\DOCUME~1\VIRTUA~1\R-TENS~1\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File  ...\R\cache\R\renv\library\comoR-4eef73a7\R-4.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32\reticulate\python\rpytools\call.py", line 16, in python_function  *
        raise error

    RuntimeError: NA/NaN argument
```

and here a minimal reproducible example.

```
 rm(list=ls())
    y = rnorm(1000)
    x= rnorm (1000)
num_classes=10
mat <- matrix( rnorm (1000*num_classes), ncol=num_classes)
x_train =x
y_train =mat
length(x_train)
dim(y_train)

model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(1)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu' ) %>%
  layer_dense(units = num_classes, activation = 'softmax')


custom_loss <- function(y_true, y_pred) {
  tt <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(y_true)) {
    tt <- tt + log(sum(exp(y_true[i,]) * y_pred[i,]))
  }
  mse <- -tt
  return(mse)
}
blank_model <-  model %>% compile(
  loss = custom_loss,
  optimizer = 'adam',
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)


model1 <- blank_model
model2 <- blank_model


history <-model1 %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train,
  epochs = 40,
  batch_size = 100
)

x_train2 =x[-1]
y_train2 =mat[-1,]

history <-model2 %>% fit(
  x_train2, y_train2,
  epochs = 40,
  batch_size = 100
)
```

The model should be easily fitted to different dataset but crashes instead without any clear reason.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- Your sum can be negative, i.e. you try to compute the logarithm of negative values -> Na losses.
- you return negative values -> optimization goes in the wrong direction

And because the tensorflow-python backend is very fragile, your session will crash.

In cito (an R package for fitting DNNs based on torch), you can also use custom loss functions (based on torch, a native (py)torch implementation for) and continue fitting:

```
library(cito)
library(torch)
custom_loss <- function(pred, true) {
  y_true = true
  y_pred = pred
  tt <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(y_true)) {
    tt <- tt + log(abs(sum(exp(y_true[i,]) * y_pred[i,])))
  }
  mse <- -tt
  return(-mse)
}
nn.fit<- dnn(Y = y_train, X = x_train,
             loss = custom_loss, lr = 0.0001)
nn.fit = continue_training(nn.fit)
```